# Multiple OR clauses in LINQ statement

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, linq

I have below LINQ Query:

```
returnVal = context.ReservationRequests
   .Where(s => ((s.RequestStatusId.HasValue) &&
                (s.RequestStatusId.Value == ResStatusId)) &&
               ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(loggedInUserRole) 
                  || s.SubmitterGroupName == loggedInUserRole) 
                  ||(s.CreatedBy == ApplicationSecurityDirector.CurrentUserGuid)))                                                         
   .Skip(skip)
   .Take(take)
  .ToList();
```

What this LINQ query is supposed to do it look into the ReservationRequests table and look for records where RequestStatusId = (suppliedRequestStatusId) and SubmitterGroupName should be equal to the logged in user role (but there are cases where user is not assigned to any role) and it should also return any requests which are created by user. 
So basically return all records if assigned to a particular group and also the requests created by logged in person if any.

The above query works fine incases where user is logged in to a group but it does not return correct results when user is not assigned to any groups. In case person is not assigned to any group it should return any records which were CreatedBy the user.

Below is a SQL query that I wrote which returns the correct amount of records for all my cases and I basically need my LINQ to be like this sql but I am not sure what I am missing here.

```
     SELECT *
  FROM [MyDB].[dbo].[ReservationRequests]
  where 
  (RequestStatusId = 2) 
  and 
  (SubmitterGroupName != null or SubmitterGroupName = null 
  or createdby = 'C5188D45-TEST-45BE-8C04-123455733A31')
```

Can someone please look into my LINQ query and see why is it returning incorrect records than my SQL ? Thanks I been looking at this for a while now!

After all the suggestion here is my updated LINQ:

```
returnVal = context.ReservationRequests
.Where(s => ((s.RequestStatusId.HasValue) &&
(s.RequestStatusId.Value == ResStatusId)) &&
(s.SubmitterGroupName == loggedInUserRole ||
s.CreatedBy == ApplicationSecurityDirector.CurrentUserGuid))
.Skip(skip)
.Take(take)
.ToList();
```

So question: Will this query work in cases loggedInUserRole  is null? In case loggedInUserRole is null then I just want to return records which are CreatedBy the logged in user.

Another Update: (9/22/2017) 9.54 AM
So I ran that statement. It works fine in cases when user is assigned to a group but when user is not assigned to a group instead of showing just the requests opened by the logged in user it returns a lot more records.

Comment: query looks diffrent from sql query

Comment: Too many redundant parentheses can help to destroy readability

Comment: Btw, your sql query doesn't make much sense either, look at `SubmitterGroupName != null or SubmitterGroupName = null OR...`

Comment: RequestStatusId?.Value == ResStatusId , try this also gives more clear query

Comment: (string.IsNullOrEmpty(loggedInUserRole) 
                  || s.SubmitterGroupName == loggedInUserRole)  this will be (string.IsNullOrEmpty(loggedInUserRole) 
                  && s.SubmitterGroupName == loggedInUserRole)

Comment: (SubmitterGroupName != null or SubmitterGroupName = null) will always be true!

Comment: sql-server != mySQL, please don't tag products not involved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`incorrect records` is relative... the records it's returning are correct I guess. We only can analyse what you're doing here and where the differences are:

In the linq query you search for

```
s.SubmitterGroupName == loggedInUserRole
```

in the SQL statement you search for

```
SubmitterGroupName != null or SubmitterGroupName = null
```

`SubmitterGroupName` cant be null and not null at the same time.So I guess, `loggedInUserRole` is null. This is with or, so this is always true. You only search then for `createdby = 'C5188D45-TEST-45BE-8C04-123455733A31'`

plus, in the linq-query you

```
.Skip(skip).Take(take)
```

this is missing in your sql-statement

so I think what you want is:

```
returnVal = context.ReservationRequests
.Where(s => ((s.RequestStatusId.HasValue) &&
(s.RequestStatusId.Value == ResStatusId)) &&
(s.SubmitterGroupName == loggedInUserRole || (s.SubmitterGroupName == null && s.CreatedBy == ApplicationSecurityDirector.CurrentUserGuid)))
.Skip(skip)
.Take(take)
.ToList();
```

Comment: @HereToLearn_ yes, this should work. This means SubmitterGroupName is either equal to loggedInUserRole or CreatedBy is equal to ApplicationSecurityDirector.CurrentUserGuid. Should be fine

Comment: So I ran that statement. It works fine in case when user is assigned to a group but when user is not assigned to a group instead of showing the requests opened by the logged in user it returns a lot more records.

Comment: try this one: `s.SubmitterGroupName == loggedInUserRole ||
(s.SubmitterGroupName == null && s.CreatedBy == ApplicationSecurityDirector.CurrentUserGuid)`

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure why you are adding all sorts of checks in there, but this should work:

```
returnVal = context.ReservationRequests
.Where(s => RequestStatusId == ResStatusId &&
    (s.SubmitterGroupName == loggedInUserRole || s.CreatedBy == ApplicationSecurityDirector.CurrentUserGuid)
.Skip(skip)
.Take(take)
.ToList();
```